# Formatting with an Option[String] in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to find a concise way to format a String with an Option[String] in Scala. I have a title String and a subtitle Option[String]. Here's what I have but I feel like there has to be a better way:

```
"Title%s".format(subtitle match
    {case Some(s) => ": %s".format(s)
     case None    => "" })
```

So if I have a subtitle, I want "Title: Subtitle", but if subtitle is `None`, I just want "Title".

Comment: `subtitle.map("Title: %s".format(_)).getOrElse("Title")`

Comment: Like Tobias said, but with string interpolation: subtitle map (t => s"Title: $t") getOrElse ("Title")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 subtitle map (t => s"Title: $t") getOrElse ("Title")
```

String interpolation is more safe than `format` because if you don't use correct variable name, or missuse it somehow it will fail at compile time. `format` will fail at run time if the number of placeholders or their types do not match format arguments.

Your version of Scala must support this feature and have it enabled.

Answer (score 5):

```
"Title%s".format(subtitle.map(": " + _).getOrElse(""))
```

`map` method is very convenient to use with the `Option` type. You can say what you want to do assuming some value is there, and don't care what happens if it's None. At the end you just provide an alternative if the latter occured (in our case empty String `""`).

Answer (score 1):

A bit cleaner than your approach but the same idea. I think this is pretty readable:

```
"Title: %s" format subtitle.getOrElse("")
```

As an aside, the following link is a great resource if you're pattern matching on an Option but think there's probably a better way: [Scala Option Cheat sheet](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: This won't work, since will produce "Title: " if `subtitle` is None, and the OP wanted "Title" in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use:

```
"Title" + subtitle.fold("")(": " + _)
```

but personally I still find that a little verbose so I have a utilities package that I import which includes

```
implicit class OptionRichClass[A](n: Option[A])
{     
  def apply[T](valNone: T, fSome: A => T): T = n.fold(valNone)(s => fSome(s))
  def mapList[T](f: (A) => T): List[T] = n.map[T](f(_)).toList      
  def flatList[T](f:(A) => List[T]): List[T] = n.fold(List[T]())(f(_))
  def flatSeq[T](f:(A) => Seq[T]): Seq[T] = n.fold(Seq[T]())(f(_))
}
```

The apply method is the important one here which would allow me to write:

```
"Title" + subtitle("", ": " + _)
```